# Screen coordinates to isometric coordinates?

Tags: mathematics, isometric, coordinates

I know this has been discussed here before, but I couldn't find an easy solution for my particular problem. I have a tile system and I'd like to convert screen coordinates into isometric tile coordinates. Here's an image to explain what I need:

[image: isometric coordinates conversion]

As you can see, the coordinates are between 0 and 1. I can't figure out a formula for the conversion though. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are (simplified version of) the formulas I use in my current project wizardwar.com:

```
 tile_x = screen_y - 0.5 + screen_x;
 tile_y = (screen_y - 0.5 - screen_x) * -1;
```

By the way: I would recommend you to use different terminology for screen-coordinates and world-coordinates to avoid mixups. I use `x` and `y` for screen coordinates and `l`eft-down and `r`ight-down for tile coordinates. This saved me from more than one brain-knot. In your example, `tile_y` would be be `l`eft-up and `tile_x` would be `r`ight-up.

Comment: Just call them sceenX or gameX if in a method where this is not clear. l and r is a bit open for interpretation because it's uncommon.